# How do you configure/enable user web pages on Fedora fc20?

Tags: apache-http-server, fedora

How do you configure enable user web pages on Fedora fc20?  I have edited
/etc/httpdr/conf.d/userdir.conf as follows which should work.  I have even ensured the folders and their parent folders exist and have at least 711 permissions.  I have tried numerous tweaks including changing the userdir to /home/*/public_html, Allow all, etc etc.  What am I doing wrong?  I have httpd.x86_64 package version 2.4.10-1.fc20 installed.

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir /var/www/*/public_html
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/*/public_html">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much browsing and looking at outdated answers on the internet I found a solution.  Since I was only able to get the link via a cache, I am re-posting the pertinent parts.

If you have done everything that you can think of, there is a high probability  (~96.42%) that your issue is you need to set the appropriate permissions for SE Linux.  This can be done as follows.

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs true

chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/username/public_html
```

Note that these are the commands I used for the userdir.conf file listed above were only the user username has permissions when done.  Change the paths as necessary for your configuration.

The users web pages are stored in /var/www/username/public_html/ and I create a symbolic link (strictly for convenience) in their home directory that points to the public_html directory.